# Is it possible to make community accidentally to reject your edit by re-editing the same post?

Tags: support, rejected-edits, community-user

I edited a question just to soon notice that I did a dumb mistake on that.

I did what I have done earlier: edited the post again (just tell me if it is a bad habit / wrong way to do it).

Then this edit was both rejected by community because of a subsequent edit and then also created as a new pending edit.

Have a look at [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17928345).

Comment: Not if you edit again within the grace period.. It adds to your pending edit. A more likely case is OP edited within their grace period causing yours to get rejected

Comment: @SurajRao Yes I tried to check that if OP did it but there were no edits in the post for a long time. Until just now that Donald Duck did something. But maybe OP started edit in a grace time period without rejecting mine first but then did not finalize the edit. Could that do it?

Comment: .. I am not sure.. yours seems to be a unique case. Its not easy to effectively synchronize simultaneous edits in a site like SO... The best you can do is make sure nothing is lost

Comment: @SurajRao Guess it is so. I have a talent of creating these kind of situations. Hopefully somebody super rep person gets interested to check this some day and provide the answer what I possibly  did wrong.

Comment: I am certain you didnt do anything particularly wrong... It just a sync problem. Just make sure all your corrections are in a single edit

Comment: Your suggested edit was rejected automatically when the OP made an other edit to their own post. That extra edit was made in the grace period, which is why you won't see another entry in the revision history. Their post was created at 12:00:12, so the grace period extended to 12:05:12, your edit was auto-rejected at 12:02:53.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I was not aware about the grace period concept but now that I read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/grace-period/info) there is more sense. It just happened that my 2nd edit was just after the OP edit then.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is compiled from comments in question.

Problem in question was related to [grace period](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/grace-period/info).

In this case

- I made the first edit which was rejected by community because of conflict with OPs edit during the grace period
- I did not notice reject before I started to correct my edit with 2nd edit
- OPs edits during the grace period do not leave any traces in edit history so it looked to me like that my own two edits were conflicting with each other